# Compilation error in typescript : Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, return-value

I have the following typescript function:

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        
        let returnUrl: string = state.url;
        this.authService.redirectUrl =  returnUrl;   
        let loginUrl: string = this.routeService.generateLoginUrl();       

        if( this.authService.isExpiredSession){
            this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe( data =>{
                if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn){
                    this.authService.logout();                 
                    this.router.navigateByUrl(loginUrl);
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            });            
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }      
    }
```

And the compiler is giving me following error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not
> include 'undefined'.

It seems to me that all code paths are covered. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: What is the origin of the authService object? Is it Firebase?

Comment: Some of those returns are inside a _callback_...

Comment: Hi @tomerpacific, authService is one of my custom services to handle user authentication

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen how? Wouldn't it return the outcome of the asynchronous call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return in the subscribe call just return the `next` call of the subscribe method, it does not actually return the function. So, your function needs to return an observable of boolean.

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        
        let returnUrl: string = state.url;
        this.authService.redirectUrl =  returnUrl;   
        let loginUrl: string = this.routeService.generateLoginUrl();       

        if( this.authService.isExpiredSession){
            return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe( 
                map(data =>{
                    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn){
                        this.authService.logout();                 
                        this.router.navigateByUrl(loginUrl);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        return true;
                    }
                })
            );            
        }
        else{
            return of(true);
        }      
    }
```

Angular behind the scenes subscribes to the returned `Observable` and uses the streamed value to decide the result.

I suggest watching Decoded Frontend on youtube to get better at angular and RxJS

Comment: thanks  @ertucode for the code sample. It got rid of the compilation error. I will check out the online resource you suggested.